# How to update a value of a key in NSObject if another key's value equal to something?

Tags: ios, swift4, nsobject

I have an NSObject class that looks like this

```
class MyItem : NSObject {

    var id: Int
    var name: String

    //other init code here
 }
```

What I want to do is, in other class, update the value of `name` when `id` is equal to something

**Now `MyViewController`**

```
var myItem = [MyItem]()
```

For example, inside array of `myItem` if `id=3`,then update the value of `name` to `"Ken"`.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this. Can somebody give me a hint on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
/// Changes The Name Of A MyItem Object Based On It's ID
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - id: Int
///   - name: String
func changeNameFromID(_ id: Int, to name: String){

    //1. Get The Index Of The Item
    guard let foundIndex = myItem.index(where: { $0.id == id }) else { return }

    //2. Get The MyItem From The Array
    let itemToAppend = myItem[foundIndex]

    //3. Change Its Name
    itemToAppend.name = name


}
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
changeNameFromID(3, to: "Ken")
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the index of the object that I want to replace then using the index replace it with the new value

```
if let row = myItem.index(where: {$0.id == yourId}) { // yourId 3
            myItem[row].name = newValue
        }
```